# How do you replace sed and wc with awk? (counting names in directories)

Tags: awk, sed, wc

I'd like to count the number of elements inside a folder. I thought of

```
function lsc { /bin/ls -l $1 | sed 1d | wc -l }
```

but then I remembered how `awk` people reduced those kind of pipes, getting rid of superfluous `grep`s and `sed`s. So, how would you do that in `awk`?

Comment: Just use `ls -1 | wc -l`  (that's a number 1 rather than a letter l) ?  Or if keen on using `awk`, you could use `ls -l | awk 'NR>1{a++}END{print a}'`

Comment: Equally, `ls -l | awk 'END{print NR-1}'` works too.

Comment: @steve Either of those will only work if no name contains embedded newlines.  Do `touch $'file\n1' $'file\n2'` and test it.

Comment: @Kusalananda when was last time you saw a filename with a newline ? serious question. I've been in the industry for nearly 15 years and never encountered a single one.

Comment: @ychaouche Since newlines are _allowed_, I'd rather write software that copes with them than knowingly writing software that would break whenever such a filename is encountered. You may, for example, have to deal with files that have names that were not written by a human, but just taken from some database. Also, since it's _easy_ to deal with all possible filenames, why not do that?

Comment: @Kusalananda fair enough. Hats off.

Comment: @ychaouche among other, less nefarious things, attackers with appropriate authority might be able to create a file name containing newlines on a system, relying on some otherwise-innocent but buggy software to try to access it and lead to privilege escalation, denial of service, etc. See for example https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2011-1155 which describes a bug that would cause a DoS attack if `logrotate` tried to handle such a file. Not writing your code to account for all possible file name characters is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I've always maintained that newlines in filenames are either (a) a bug in some tool, or (b) something malicious or nefarious.  Even if they are technically "allowed".

Comment: @sitaram I still find it fascinating that everyone finds it "acceptable" and not at *least* a  fundamental design "oddity", like, did what did the persons in charge had in mind for allowing `\n` in file names, for what usage ?

Comment: It's not about selecting which chars to allow, it's about selecting which ones to disallow. Where would you stop disallowing characters? Maybe disallow backslashes or other white space chars or punctuation chars or...? Why create file names containing any given char - who cares? The only 2 characters disallowed in file names are NUL because C-strings are NUL-terminated and `/` because directory paths are `/`-separated. There's simply no reason to disallow any other characters, people just have to write their code correctly and, as @kusalananda mentioned, it's easy to do so.

Comment: @edmorton tradeoffs are hard to find

Comment: @ychaouche -- Maybe there was divergence of opinion, or maybe in some cases second thoughts.  IMO, people that hide behind "the standard allows it, so the script must support it", need to read section 2.2 ("Standards permit the exclusion of bad filenames") of [this page](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html) or section 4.8 ("Filename portability") of "The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7 IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 Edition", [General Concepts](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need for `ls`, `sed`, `wc` or `awk`.

If you simply want to count how many names a pattern expands to, then you can do that with

```bsh
set -- *
echo "$#"
```

The `set` command sets the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc.) to the names matching the `*` pattern.  This automatically sets the special variable `$#` to the number of set positional parameters, i.e. the number of names matching the given pattern.

In `bash` or in a shell that has named arrays, you can use

```bsh
names=(*)
echo "${#names[@]}"
```

This works similarly, but sets the elements of the `names` array to the names resulting from the expansion of the `*` pattern.  The variable expansion `${#names[@]}` will be the number of elements in the `names` array.

An issue with this is that if the pattern doesn't match anything, it will remain unexpanded, so you get a count of 1 (even though the directory is empty).  To fix this in the `bash` shell, set the `nullglob` shell option with `shopt -s nullglob`.  By setting this shell option, patterns that do not match anything will be removed completely.

In `bash`, if you additionally want to count hidden names, set the `dotglob` shell option with `shopt -s dotglob`.

Your function could look something like this in `bash`:

```bsh
lsc () (
    shopt -s nullglob
    set -- "$1"/*
    echo "$#"
)
```

Note the use of `( ... )` for the function body to avoid setting `nullglob` in the calling shell.

Or, for `/bin/sh`:

```bsh
lsc () {
    set -- "$1"/*
    if [ -e "$1" ] || [ -L "$1" ]; then
        echo "$#"
    else
        echo 0
    fi
}
```

The `if` statement here makes sure that the first positional parameter is the name of an actual file and not an unexpanded pattern (due to not matching anything). The `-e` ("exists") must be true for us to trust the number in `$#`. If it isn't true, then we additionally check whether the name refers to a symbolic link with the `-L` test.  If this is true, we know that the first thing that the pattern expanded to was a "dead" symbolic link (a symbolic link pointing to a non-existent file), and we trust `$#` to be correct. If both tests fail, we know that we didn't match anything and therefore output `0`.

Answer (score 0):

First, your one-liner function definition is incorrect. Presence of
the `function` keyword indicates that you might use Bash and this is
what it says under `Shell Function Definitions` in man bash:

```
function name [()] compound-command [redirection]
```

while the *compound command* is defined as:

```
{ list; }
```

So it should be:

```
function lsc { /bin/ls -l $1 | sed 1d | wc -l; }
```

But even though it's technically correct it will not work well, see
[Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do
instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

You can print a number of files and directories in the given directory
using awk like that:

```
awk 'END {print ARGC - 1}' *
```

but notice that if at least one of the arguments expanded by shell in
place of `*` is a directory awk complains:

```
$ awk 'END {print ARGC - 1}' *
awk: warning: command line argument `dir1' is a directory: skipped
```

But anyway, the result is still fine and you can redirect errors to
/dev/null:

```
awk 'END {print ARGC - 1}' * 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: If you change `END` to `BEGIN` then you won't get those warnings since awk doesn't have to open any files (in END NF must be set to the number of fields present in the last file opened, for example, while nothing related to file contents is set in BEGIN). In some older awk versions you may need to add `; exit` before the `}`